# Split a variable and keep first part

Tags: r

I have a variable that is composed of three numbers separated by "." where the first two numbers are the ID and the last is the rep number. For example in "3.4.1" the ID would be "3.4." and the rep "1". I want to split the numbers and keep only the "ID" numbers as a new variable. Although I was able to get what I wanted I'm sure there must be a much simpler way to solve this. Here is a toy example:

```
plant<-c("2.3.1","2.3.2","1.2.1","1.2.2","12.3.1","12.3.2")
height<-c(2.3,2.1,2.5,2.6,3,2.9)
d<-data.frame(plant,height)
d$ID<-paste(lapply(strsplit(as.character(d$plant),"[.]"), `[[`, 1),".",lapply(strsplit(as.character(d$plant),"[.]"), `[[`, 2), sep = "")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` (escape the dot `\\.` as it is a metacharacter) followed by one or more characters that are not a dot (`[^.]+`) until the end of the string and replace it with `""`.

```
d$ID <- sub("\\.[^.]+$", "", d$plant)
d$ID
#[1] "2.3"  "2.3"  "1.2"  "1.2"  "12.3" "12.3"
```

If we need the `.` also at the end (which seems unlikely)

```
sub("[^.]+$", "", d$plant)
#[1] "2.3."  "2.3."  "1.2."  "1.2."  "12.3." "12.3."
```

Comment: It worked. why don't you escape the dot in the second example?

Comment: @Cba It is inside the `[]` where it reads not as the metacharacter `.`